# TSQL Large Insert of Relational Data, W/ Foreign Key Upsert

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql, upsert

Relatively simple problem.
`Table A` has `ID int` PK, unique `Name varchar(500)`, and `cola, colb`, etc
`Table B` has a foreign key to `Table A`.

So, in the application, we are generating records for both table A and table B into DataTables in memory.

We would be generating thousands of these records on a very large number of "clients".

Eventually we make the call to store these records. However, records from table A may already exist in the database, so we need to get the primary keys for the records that already exist, and insert the missing ones. Then insert all records for table B with the correct foreign key.

**Proposed solution:**

I was considering sending an xml document to SQL Server to open as a rowset into `TableVarA`, update `TableVarA` with the primary keys for the records that already exist, then insert the missing records and output that to `TableVarNew`, I then select the `Name` and primary key from `TableVarA` union all `TableVarNew`.

Then in code populate the correct FKs into `TableB` in memory, and insert all of these records using `SqlBulkCopy`.

Does this sound like a good solution? And if so, what is the best way to populate the FKs in memory for `TableB` to match the primary key from the returned DataSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a plan - but I think the handling of `Table A` can be simpler (a single in-memory table/table variable should be sufficient):

- have a `TableVarA` that contains all rows for `Table A`
- update the `ID` for all existing rows with their ID (should be doable in a single SQL statement)
- insert all non-existing rows (that still have an empty `ID`) into `Table A` and make a note of their `ID`

This could all happen in a single table variable - I don't see why you need to copy stuff around....

Once you've handled your `Table A`, as you say, update `Table B`'s foreign keys and bulk insert those rows in one go.

What I'm not quite clear on is how `Table B` references `Table A` - you just said it had an FK, but you didn't specify what column it was on (assuming on `ID`). Then how are your rows from `Table B` referencing `Table A` for new rows, that aren't inserted yet and thus don't have an `ID` in `Table A` yet?

Comment: This would be done on the unique Name.
Which portions of inserting Table A are you talking about changing?  That instead of selecting from both table vars with a union, that I update TableVarA with the results from TableVarNew and return that as a DataSet?

Comment: Also, I saw your answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006472/fast-insert-relationalnormalized-data-tables-into-sql-server-2008-database
And that sounded pretty smart, but that seemed relating more to data import, rather than optimizing something that will be happening a lot.  IE: Lots of Clients will be sending lots of records lots of the time, so trying to make sure we quickly insert all of these records is pretty important.

Comment: @Thx: I didn't like the fact you intended to use at least two (or three?) different "TableA" variables and merging around stuff. I think you can do all the necessary operations with a single TableA variable. Also: yes, maybe the idea of pushing everything to the server into staging tables using `SqlBulkCopy` and then doing all the fixing up there isn't such a bad idea after all!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than a complete answer but I was running out of room so please don't vote it down for not being up to answer criteria.

My concern would be that evaluating a set for missing keys and then inserting in bulk you take a risk that the key got added elsewhere in the mean time. You stated this could be from a large number of clients so it this is going to happen.  Yes you could wrap it in a big transaction but big transactions are hogs would lock out other clients.

My thought is to deal with those that have keys in bulk separate assuming there is no risk the PK would be deleted.   A TVP is efficient but you need explicit knowledge of which got processed.  I think you need to first search on Name to get a list of PK that exists then process that via TVP.

For data integrity process the rest one at a time via a stored procedure that creates the PK as necessary.

Thousands of records is not scary (millions is).   Large number of "clients" that is the scary part.